# onclick open sub menu, on click close sub menu?

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, onclick, dom-events

On this page http://kimcolemanprojects.com/ I need to have a drop down menu that opens on click and closes again on click of same anchor. Like it works on this site http://angela-moore.co.uk/

This is my html for the menu so far:

```
<div class="left" id="nav">
<ul id="menu">
<li id="light">
<a href="lighting_video.html">Lighting + Video</a>
   <ul style="display: none;">
     <li><a href="django_django.html">Django Django</a></li>
     <li><a href="suntrap.html">Suntrap</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li id="photo">
<a href="photograms.html">Photograms</a>
</li>
<li id="about">
<a class="active" href="about.html">About</a>
</li></ul>
</div><!--end nav-->
```

As you can see I only need it to work within one list item. I need help writing the Javascript for this.

So when on index page the user can see three links lighting + video, Photograms, About. When user clicks on lighting + video a sub menu opens beneath with more links. Then it will close again if the user clicks again on lighting + video.  The same can happen with each of the initial three links on the index page.

Answer (score 3):

Quite Simple..

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<div id="navigation">
<p><a href="#" id="toggle">Menu</a></p>
<ul id="menu">



    <li><a href="/#" class="book-campaigns">Menu 1</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol</a></li><li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol2</a></li><li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol</a></li><li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol2</a></li>
    </ul></li>

    <li><a href="/#" class="book-campaigns">Menu 2</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol</a></li><li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol2</a></li><li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol</a></li><li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol2</a></li>
    </ul></li>

            <li><a href="/#" class="book-campaigns">Menu 3</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol</a></li><li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol2</a></li><li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol</a></li><li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol2</a></li>
    </ul></li>

            <li><a href="/#" class="book-campaigns">Menu 4</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol</a></li><li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol2</a></li><li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol</a></li><li><a href="#"  class="lol">lol2</a></li>
    </ul></li>
```

This will be your HTML container etc, under this you will need your javascript to control that hiding and changing!! You can add some styling also if you feel artistic!

```
<script>
var showMenuText = $('#toggle').text();
var hideMenuText = 'Close';

$('#navigation ul').hide();
$('#navigation ul a.active+ul').show();

hideMenu = function() {
    $('#navigation ul#menu').hide();
    $('#navigation').removeClass('open');
    $('#toggle').text(showMenuText);
}

$('#toggle').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation(); event.preventDefault();
    $('#navigation ul#menu').toggle();
    $('#navigation').toggleClass('open');
    var toggleText = $('#toggle').text();
    (toggleText == showMenuText) ? $(this).text(hideMenuText) : $(this).text(showMenuText);
});

$('ul#menu > li > a').click(function(event){
    $this = $(this);
    if( $this.hasClass('page') ) parent.location = $this.attr('href');
    if( $this.hasClass('home') ) { parent.location = '/'; }

    event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation();
    if( $this.hasClass('active') ) var justclosed = true;
    $('a.active').removeClass('active').next('ul').hide();
    if(!justclosed) $this.addClass('active').next('ul').show();
});

</script>
```

This is a simple HTML Example and you can execute it how you like.

Comment: Also to clarify, you are loading the scripts end of the render, it can improve the performance of your site ALTHOUGH  some JS can always be required prior to render so choose carefully.